# Script.aculo.us Sliders with 2 colors

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous

How can I define different color, other than the background color of the track, for area between the two handles?

**Update 08/06/2013:**
I have created a Price range slider with two handles, with the following HTML

```
<div id="price_slider">
    <span id="price_handle_min">&gt;</span>
    <span id="price_handle_max">&lt;</span>
</div>
```

Following JS, with Prototype V1.7 & script.aculo.us slider.js v1.8.2

Used the following script, to setup the slider:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    var handles = [$('price_handle_min'), $('price_handle_max')];
    var sliderValues = [0, 100];
    var slider = new Control.Slider(handles, 'price_slider', {
        range : $R(0, 100, false),
        step : 1,
        sliderValue : sliderValues,
        values : [0,20,40,60,80,100],
        restricted : true,
        onChange : function(val) {
            alert(val);
        },
        onSlide : function(val) {
            alert(val);
        }
    });
});
```

Current Slider:

[image]

Desired Slider:

[image]

Comment: it would go a long way if you show us what you have done

Comment: @epoch Please review the update, is this what you were asking for?

Comment: perfect, you would get a lot more responses when questions are phrased like this

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing track color between 2 Slider handels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972442/changing-track-color-between-2-slider-handels)